# is it safe to pass mysql where clause column names and operators to PHP ajax script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to build a robust, simple, safe, catch-all way to pass dynamic SQL queries via ajax to a php script.  I don't think I have come up with the winner yet, but what I have now seems to work for my applications.  I wish to have just one php script on my web server that take input variables to build an SQL query, execute the query, and return the results to the website.  Executing the query and returning the results are not the problem.  The problem is the proper and secure way to pass these input variables to the script.

The biggest confusion I am having is **how to produce produce the WHERE clause** still being able to account for all the different WHERE clauses that are possible.

Let's say that the PHP file on the server is called `master.php`.

From Javascirpt I have this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "master.php",
  dataType: "xml",
  data: { 
      schema: "the_schema", 
      table: "the_table",
      select: JSON.stringify(['col_name_1','col_name_2','...']),
      where: JSON.stringify(["status","!=","Some Status","and","STR_TO_DATE(date,","%m/%d/%Y",")",">","(date(now())","-","INTERVAL","30","day)"])
  },
  success: function (data){
      alert(data);
      // of course here I will actually do something with the data, this is just for illustration of how the data is returned to the web page.
  }
});
```

The `data` variable will either be XML data from the database, of a string: "failure: error msg".

In the `master.php` script on the server I have this:

```
<?php
    include '/config_file.php'; //checks user permissions and establishes mysqli connection

    /*
     * Table and schema are required 
     */
    $table = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['table']);
    $schema = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['schema']);

    /*
     * Select section
     * if there is no select then just use *
     */
    if (isset($_POST['select'])){
        $select_string = 'select ';
        $select = json_decode($_POST['select']);
        foreach($select as $key => $value){
            $select_string .= '`'.$mysqli->real_escape_string($value).'`, ';
        }
    }else{
        $select_string = 'select * ';
    }

    /*
     * Where section
     */
    if (isset($_POST['where'])){
        $where = json_decode($_POST['where']);
    }

    if (isset($where)){
        $where_string = ' where ';
        foreach ($where as $key => $value){
            if (strpos($value, ' ') !== false or strpos($value, '%') !== false){
                // if there is a space or % in the value, it must be a string so enclose it in quotes
                $where_string .= '"'.$mysqli->real_escape_string($value).'" ';
            }else{
                $where_string .= $mysqli->real_escape_string($value).' ';
            }
        }
        $where_string = rtrim($where_string);
    }

    if(!isset($where_string)) $where_string = '';

    /*
     * End of Where Section
     */


    /*
     * Build SQL
     */
    $SQL = $select_string.'from '.$schema.'.'.$table.$where_string;

    //...continue to execute query and echo results
?>
```

So as you can see, every part of the `where` array gets escaped and added to the query, even the column names and the operators (=, !=, >, <, etc).

Also as you can see it seems little crazy they I am passing separate strings for every part of this part of the where clause -> `and STR_TO_DATE(date, "%m/%d/%Y" ) > (date(now()) - INTERVAL 30 day)`

If you all have

1. experience with passing dynamic where clauses to the ajax script
2. if you have a better idea
3. see a security hole in the scripts

please let me know.  hopefully we can get a nice, all purpose data basing script going.

Thanks!

Comment: `$select = 'select '; $select = json_decode($_POST['select']);` Shouldn't the second line be `.=`?

Comment: @Hiddle... that is a great point... i can't believe the script has been working so far like this... haha, It should be 2 different variables.  I will change it.

Comment: How broad are the things added to the `WHERE` clause? Could they not be done with a list of options?

Comment: What do you stand to gain from this? Instead of writing database-specific code in the backend (where it is out of sight and in plain SQL) you will end up writing it in the frontend where it is viewable by everyone and written in your own custom, non-interoperable format. As an added bonus, you get to worry about security holes. **Why?**

Comment: @Grim yes I think you could use a list of options.  Which you may need to change in the future when you need to use a new option.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind I really think that might be the way to go. I'm pretty sure it'll be easier to add new options in the future than deal with the issues leaving it alone might cause =]

Comment: @Jon thanks for your comment.  My Motivation is that when creating a large, custom info-management system, I would not need to create new scripts on the back end (they all basically do that same thing: execute a query and return the results).  I still have to add the ajax callback code, so I can put my parameters in this ajax code.  I am trying to save my self work.  That is basically it.  But as you mention maybe I am risking too much to save this work.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: You should use some kind of framework (why not one of the well known ones) to group multiple data provider "functions" into a single file. Having a separate script handle each AJAX call is inefficient (even naive); that's what you should be working on to improve.

Comment: @Jon -  thanks for the recommendations.  If you don't mind, what is one of these frameworks you are referring to?  Do you mean like I would just make one script, but I just pass this one script a variable -> `var arg1 = 'descriptive_value';`? I could make a function in the PHP script that returns the pre-built query, like this ; `$SQL = function_to_return_query($_POST['arg1']);`

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: CakePHP, Symfony, Yii, Kohana are all mainstream frameworks. You would specify a URL that forwards to a specific class method (conceptually the same as passing a parameter). Then for each new URL the only thing you 'd have to do is write a new function in an existing Controller class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I do not recommend this kind of approach where you expose the Database column names in the javascript, which is completely dangerous.

Simple example is you can manipulate the ajax parameters in browser level and execute it against your database. You are simply enabling the hackers to get more information about your data.

For example I could stop the where close so that i can see all your data from your database by executing a call without where parameters. If you want to develop such dynamic queries, make sure you are using some mappings between the ajax passed parameters and the real table columns so that the columns are not exposed to the hackers directly.

Thats the basic security issue that I could see in this script.

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: "you expose the Database column names in the javascript, which is completely dangerous" - how so? I mean, if you can inject the SQL you need to do something bad like alter a column, you can inject the SQL that gives you the column names.

Comment: Yes I was wondering how exposing the column names is inherently dangerous?

Comment: The reason is, when a hacker got to know about the tables columns and table name, he could be able to produce any set of selection statements based on your code. Simply its easy to get all the data of from the database tables, by giving the table name only without the where close. That's the concern i saw in the above code.